# Spiral bar graph using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate this plot, particularly the spiral bar chart for **INDUSTRIAL**. Any idea how to do this using ggplot2?
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's pretty specific (and not really useful outside of this use), I think you'll need to write that yourself.

Comment: Also generally a violation of data visualization best practices as the human visual system is poorly adapted to quantitatively judging length of nonlinear, non-parallel, non-aligned, non-adjacent shapes.

Comment: thanks for your comments r2evans and Dan. I'm just trying to replicate it for a data challenge.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case have you tried [`geom_ribbon()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_ribbon.html)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The actual code for this is quite straightforward using geomtextpath. It's getting the data in the right format that is difficult:

```r
library(geomtextpath)

df <- data.frame(
  Domain = rep(c("BUSINESS  12", "CLASSICAL  98", "PROFESSIONAL  152",
                 "SCIENTIFIC  161", "NORMAL  383", "INDUSTRIAL  2252"),
               times = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 202)),
  x = c(0, 212, 0, 298, 0, 410, 0, 381, 0, 583, 0,
        800 + 80 * sin(seq(0, pi, length = 100)), 
        80 - 80 * sin(seq(0, pi, length = 100)), 400),
  y = c(8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 
        2.6 + 0.4 * cos(seq(0, pi, length = 100)), 
        1.8 + 0.4 * cos(seq(0, pi, length = 100)), 1.4)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_textpath(aes(label = Domain), size = 3,
                colour = "#907f6e", hjust = 0, linewidth = 3.8) + 
  theme_void() + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(
    fill = radialGradient(c("#d8cabe", "#ccb5a1"))),
    plot.margin = margin(50, 10, 50, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: geomtextpath has already been one of my fav new packages before it was even on CRAN :D amazing what one can do with it. I'm now even more convinced that the name is not ideal given you can curve more than only text.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this is so specific (and so against modern data visualization best practices), that Photoshop is probably the best tool for the job. That said, here's a version that chops up the longest bar into multiple pieces. Not a spiral, but the same basic idea of collapsing a disproportionately large y-axis value by letting it move across the x-axis.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  vocation = c('business', 'classical', 'industrial'),
  enrollment = c(12, 98, 2252)
)

max.bar.size <- 600
df.cut <- df %>% 
  group_by(vocation) %>% 
  summarize(
    bar = 1:(floor(enrollment / max.bar.size) + 1),
    enrollment = c(rep(max.bar.size, floor(enrollment / max.bar.size)), enrollment %% max.bar.size)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(bar = as.character(bar))

ggplot(data = df.cut, aes(x = vocation, y = enrollment, group = bar)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = 'single'))
```

[image]